# Schengen tourist visa: Work details of spouse accompanying short term work permit traveler

Tags: working-visas, schengen, belgium, europe

I am planning travel to Belgium on a work permit in the month of February. Since it is a short term work permit, my wife plans to accompany me for a brief period so that we can roam around much of Europe during the weekends. We are planning to apply for a regular tourist visa for her, enclosing my work permit details in her cover letter too.

Incidentally she happens to leave her current job at about the same time and plans to join a new job once she is back.
I do understand because of the above clause she wont be able to present a letter of no-objection from employer(approval of leaves for travel), as she would effectively be job-less during that brief time. Although we do plan to present her financial holdings (bank statements, income tax fillings from prev. years, insurance policies etc.) along with her visa application.
Does anybody think that her visa application case might still be a shaky one because of missing of a current employment letter?